# how to fix jquery ajax data shows [object Object]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

error show [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

```
$var address = $('[name=address]').val();
$('.loader1').show();
$.ajax({
    url: "address.json",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        'address': address,
        'street' : global.street
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.error !== undefined) {
            alert(data.error);
        } else {
            $('#deposit-address').val(data.address);
        }
        $('.loader1').hide();                 
    }
});
return false;
```

and json file

```
${"address": [
    {
        "street":"1",
        "address":"730 test"
    }, {
        "street":"2",
        "address":"630 test"
    }, {
        "street":"3",
        "address":"530 test"
    } 
]}
```

Comment: I hope your JSON doesn't really have a `$` in front of it.

Comment: @Andy given that the output is being given as `[object Object]`, it appears that jQuery is parsing it as JSON correctly, so it would seem to be a typo.

Comment: sorry I put the $ that do not let me post

Answer (score 0):

`data.address` is an array, so you either need to loop over each of them, or pull a specific property out that you require:

```
$('#deposit-address').val(data.address[0].address); // = '730 test'
```

Comment: thanks, json file is missing me, so searching for examples and I need to put that which would be the correct json file, as you would enter

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: i need fix the url: "address.json", data which would have to put

Comment: which would put the data in the file address.json

Comment: I'm struggling to understand you, but it sounds like you're trying to figure out the URL to your .json file - which I can't help you with. That's down to your own file structure.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code ok

> function createDepositAddress(){
>       var address = $('[name=address]').val();
>       $('.loader1').show();
>               $.ajax({
>                   url: "address.json", <------- missing file
>                   type: "post",
>                   dataType: "json",
>                   data: {
>                       'address': address,
>                       'plan' : global.street
>                   },
>                   success: function(data) {
>                       if (data.error !== undefined) {
>                           alert(data.error);
>                       } else {
>                           $('#deposit-address').val(data.address);
>                       }
>                       $('.loader1').hide();
>                   }
>               });
>           return false; }

Comment: my address.json is missing i need create new one, the data which would be put in the